# marionette todomvc extend error

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, requirejs, marionette, todomvc

```
TodoMVC.module "TodoList", (TodoList, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  # TodoList Router
  # ---------------
  #
  # Handle routes to show the active vs complete todo items
  TodoList.Router = Marionette.AppRouter.extend
    appRoutes: "*filter": "filterItems"

  # TodoList Controller (Mediator)
  # ------------------------------
  #
  # Control the workflow and logic that exists at the application
  # level, above the implementation detail of views and models
  TodoList.Controller = ->
    @todoList = new App.Todos.TodoList()

  _.extend TodoList.Controller::,

    # Start the app by showing the appropriate views
    # and fetching the list of todo items, if there are any
    start: ->
      @showHeader @todoList
      @showFooter @todoList
      @showTodoList @todoList
      App.bindTo @todoList, "reset add remove", @toggleFooter, this
      @todoList.fetch()

    showHeader: (todoList) ->
      header = new App.Layout.Header(collection: todoList)
      App.header.show header

    showFooter: (todoList) ->
      footer = new App.Layout.Footer(collection: todoList)
      App.footer.show footer

    showTodoList: (todoList) ->
      App.main.show new TodoList.Views.ListView(collection: todoList)

    toggleFooter: ->
      App.footer.$el.toggle @todoList.length

    # Set the filter to show complete or all items
    filterItems: (filter) ->
      App.vent.trigger "todoList:filter", filter.trim() or ""


  # TodoList Initializer
  # --------------------
  #
  # Get the TodoList up and running by initializing the mediator
  # when the the application is started, pulling in all of the
  # existing Todo items and displaying them.
  TodoList.addInitializer ->
    controller = new TodoList.Controller()
    new TodoList.Router(controller: controller)
    controller.start()
```

Uncaught NoMethodError: Method 'filterItems' was not found on the controller

I've taken the [TodoMVC example for Marionette](https://github.com/derickbailey/todomvc/tree/marionette/labs/architecture-examples/backbone_marionette), and converted it to CoffeeScript using [js2coffee](http://js2coffee.org/) and I'm using requirejs. I'm not sure why this is happening, as I've added no real custom code. If there is any additional information I can include, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had this error.

The problem is in the following code:

```
TodoList.Controller = ->
    @todoList = new App.Todos.TodoList()
```

It will add `return` in front of the second line once converted to JS. For me, adding `true` as the next line solved the problem.

```
TodoList.Controller = ->
    @todoList = new App.Todos.TodoList()
    true
```